# Text styling breaks after a child element inside it

Tags: html, css

I have a simple `<p>` element with text in it and halfway through the text I want to insert an image. For some reason the text that comes after the image isn't styled according to the stylesheet:

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text is styled according to the stylesheet.
  <div></div>
  Text loses its styling.
</p>
```

Why is that?

Comment: a `div` inside a `p` is not allowed. `p` stands for a paragraph which is a text block of flow text.  The auto-correction feature of the browser will try to correct your error and by that break your style. It will close the paragraph at the start of the div.

Comment: You've inserted a div here, not an image, which is quite different.

Comment: @ralph.m Yes, that's beacause I want to add a description of the image under it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Markup is invalid! Use a [Markup Valdiator](https://validator.w3.org/nu/#textarea) to check if your projects are validly coded.

The issue is, that paragraph (`<p>`) is a container solely for a text block where flow-text is expected. A `div` however is a block container and as such not a container for flow-text unlike a `span`.

Modern mainstream browsers have an auto-correction feature to fix most mistakes in the code to still render the document and not completely break itself.

Your code will be corrected by browsers like this:

```html
<p>
  Text is styled according to the stylesheet.
</p>
<div></div>
Text loses its styling.
```

As such you will realize why the second line is no longer influenced by the CSS styling.

#### Solution

You stated in the comments:

> @ralph.m Yes, that's beacause I want to add a description of the image under it.

And this point I have to say, that a div is not a suitable container either. The correct way is to use `figure` and `figcaption`.

```html
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg">
  <figcaption>This is just a Placeholder Image</figcaption>
</figure>
```

However, as said above, it is not correct to include anything else than flow-text inside a paragraph. So you have to split the markup as follows:

```html
<p>Text is styled according to the stylesheet.</p>
<figure>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg">
  <figcaption>This is just a Placeholder Image</figcaption>
</figure>
<p>More flow-text.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Breaking it into two p tags would work.

This is because

tag is a block-level element used to represent a paragraph of text. It should only contain inline elements such as text or other inline elements like span, a, strong etc.

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text is styled according to the stylesheet.
</p>
  <div></div>
<p>
  Text does not lose its styling.
</p>
```

Or try using a span tag or any inline element for that matter

```css
p {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Text is styled according to the stylesheet.
  <span></span><br>
  Text does not lose its styling.
</p>
```

Comment: no t just any inline element but only flow text. A picture within a paragraph is actually not semantically correct either as it is not flow text.

Answer (score -1):

Because you defined two different blocks.

The `<p>` element is a block-level element and should contain only inline-level elements, not other block-level elements like `<div>`. When defining a class, its settings will affect only the defined block-level element, not the blocks that comes after it.

```
<p>
  Text is styled according to the stylesheet.
  <!-- The <img> tag is the correct tag to use. -->
  <img src="your-image-url.jpg" alt="Your Image Description">
  Text retains its styling.
</p>
```

Every HTML tag has its own default settings that fit its purpose.

Comment: the reason is not that p is a block-level element. Because the content is expected to be flow text. Otherwise, a div could not contain a div either.